# Laravel reset password submit miss parameter from subdomain variable

Tags: php, laravel

I put the Laravel auth in a subdomain with a variable `slug`.

When I submit Reset Password I get the error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: password.reset] [URI: password/reset/{token}]

```php
Route::domain('{business_slug}.' . env('APP_URL'))->middleware(['business.slug'])->group(function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

```php
public function showLinkRequestForm($business_slug)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.email', ['business_slug' => $business_slug]);
}
```

```
{{ route('password.email', ['business_slug' => $business_slug]) }}
```

Comment: `{token}` is the missing parameter. What's the URL are you trying to send?

Comment: @senty `http://jurdekker.onlineroosters.test/password/email`

Comment: You seem like your url is `http://jurdekker.onlineroosters.test/password/reset/{token}` and `token` in url is missing in your instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reset Password cycle is:

The `Auth::routes()` routes are like this:

```
// 1) Show I forget password page
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')
      ->name('password.request');

// 2) Send the reset link to user's email
Route::post('/password/email', 'Auth\ForgetPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')
     ->name('password.email');

// At this point, you should receive an email with a url looking like:
// example.com/reset/password/123123
// where 123123 is your {token}

// 3) From that link in the email, show reset password page
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')
       ->name('password.reset');

// 4) Reset the password
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

You can also try `php artisan route:list` to see all your routes.

---

Edit: I think it's related with the url you get in your email. In your `.env` file, make sure `APP_URL` is right; in your case:

```
APP_URL=http://jurdekker.onlineroosters.test
```

Comment: It only shows the error when it is in the variable subdomain. I think he misses the variable `business_slug` and not the `token`

Comment: Can you `dd($business_slug)` in your `sendResetLinkEmail`?